# Create a constraint on multiple columns in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a MySQL table in order to manage building entrance methods in a city described by the following model:

```py
class EntranceMethod(db.Model):
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    building_id = ForeignKey('building.id', nullable=False)
    user_id = ForeignKey('user.id', nullable=False)
    card_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    gate = Column(Enum('A', 'B', 'C'), nullable=False)
```

In a building, a person can have many cards, which can be used to identify them and allow them to go through certain gates. However, these cards also can be used to do that at other buildings.

In a building scope, I want to ensure that:

- With a specific gate, an user cannot use more than 1 card to enter. (They can enter the building at other gates by this card but cannot use another card at this gate).

So I created an unique constraint: (`building_id`, `user_id`, `gate`)

- A card belongs to only 1 user.

What constraint should I make? I thought of a unique constraint for `building_id`, `card_name`, `gate` will solve the problem, but its just say that, *'This card can be used by only one user on each gate'*. The case, user U use card K at gate A, and user V use card K at gate B, is still able to be.

For example, I have some records (one building scope):

| user_id | card_name | gate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | card1-1 | A |
| user1 | card1-2 | B |
| user2 | card2-1 | C |
| user2 | card1-1 | B |

The unique constraint (`building`, `user_id`, `gate`) is sastified, but the card named `card1-1` belongs to 2 users.

Comment: How does the unique constraint on (building_id, user_id, gate) fail to achieve the desired result? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with sample data and results.

Comment: @GordThompson That unique constraint make my table to sastify the 1st condition, but not the 2nd one.

Answer (score 1):

Your constraint `(building_id, user_id, gate)` implies the uniqueness of an entrance method for a given user.
Verbally, it means

**"One user cannot have more than one entrance method for a gate in a building"**

or

**"One gate in a building cannot have more than 1 way of entering a single user"**

Since you are not handling card uniqueness in any way, it's not possible to imply that `User1` will not have the same card as `User2`. However, your primary condition would still be satisfied - one user will be able to use only one card ( whatever text you will put into the `card` field of the `EntranceMethod` ) to pass through.

Since there is ONLY ONE entrance method for a gate for each user, there would be no duplicates of `card` field for a given `User`, `building_id` and `gate`.

If you'd like to additionally ensure that the users won't share their cards to enter, you may introduce a `Card` model, with a `ForeignKey` to `User` model. This way, one card instance will be attached to only one `User`.

However, this method implies that you have to validate `EntranceMethod` upon creation - additionally check if the `card_id` is one of the user's cards.

Comment: I've already created an `UniqueConstraint('building_id', 'user_id', 'gate')`. But the main problem is how to make a pair of values (building_id, card) would go with only one value of user_id.

Comment: @Goomoonryong, I edited the question, please, take a look

Comment: your expression is so clear and right what I meant. I think it'll work for my problem partially and I'll try it on so I give you an upvote. Thanks.